# IE9 input number

Tags: jquery, html, internet-explorer

First of all I am aware that IE9 does not have `input[type="number"]` support, and I am fine with it displaying as `type="text"`; I am not looking for a polyfill.

However, when trying to select number-type inputs in jQuery with `$('input[type="number"]')`, IE9 doesn't actually select anything because its type-attribute has changed to text.  This is not the case for other input types it does not support, such as date and time, where it will leave the type-attribute as-is but just change its type-property to text.

[Basic codepen of the issue](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZGarLJ)

Why does this happen?

**Edit for reference**: I should have specified, but I was only testing this in the IE9 document mode in IE11.  Jonathan Sampson clarified that this does not occur in actual IE9.

Comment: try to select them by some class you add to them

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're testing Internet Explorer 11's document mode for IE 9. This isn't the same as testing a real version of Internet Explorer 9. As you report, it does appear as though IE 9's document mode in IE 11 will change an `<input type="number">` into `<input type="text">`.

I will file an issue on this and have our engineers investigate the matter further.

When testing Internet Explorer 9, it's always best to test in a *real version*. You can stream IE 9 through http://browserstack.com, or download free virtual machines on http://dev.modern.ie/tools/vms.

*Original Answer*

While Internet Explorer 9 changes the `type` property, it doesn't change the *attribute*. As a result, I'm not able to repro the issue you're reporting. Both jQuery, and querySelector match inputs with the number type in Internet Explorer 9.

[image]

Comment: Well then... I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong, because [I'm getting 0 when I run that fiddle](http://i.imgur.com/6RYMsiG.png).

Comment: You're not testing Internet Explorer 9; you're testing IE 11's document mode for 9.

Comment: The IE 9 document mode *often* does function the same as IE 9, but not always. This may be a bug with our emulation functionality; I work on the IE team and will open up an issue for our engineers to look into. For now, rest assured that users of *real IE9* will not experience this issue.

Comment: >.> And I can't get an actual IE9 for testing because of an IT policy.  Well thanks for the help, sorry for the waste.

Comment: @DesjardinsM You can stream IE 9 through http://browserstack.com. I would encourage your IT department to get an account there, as it gives you direct access to *real* versions of Internet Explorer (as well as many other browsers, and device-emulations).

Comment: " And I can't get an actual IE9 for testing because of an IT policy." BUT you support it? lol Virtual Machines http://dev.modern.ie/tools/vms/